# How to upload file to HDFS in Ubuntu

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I'm new to hadoop, Using single node `hadoop 1.2.1` in `ubuntu 14.04 LTS`. I want to upload a file to hadoop for execution but i dont know how to use `copyFromLocal` command.. plz tell me how to upload a file
my source file path `"/home/saurabh/downloads/examples.jar"`
and my hadoop is at `/usr/local/hadoop/`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your hadoop is in PATH then you could do this:

```
hadoop fs -put /home/saurabh/downloads/examples.jar /path/in/hdfs
```

> If your hadoop is not in PATH, then you should either export HADOOP_HOME or you could also cd into the folder where you have installed hadoop and then execute the command.

you can also do the same with:

```
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /home/saurabh/downloads/examples.jar /path/in/hdfs
```

where `/path/in/hdfs` is where you want to copy the file in HDFS to, assume if you want to copy the file to `/user/saurabh` in HDFS then the command would be something like this:

```
hadoop fs -put /home/saurabh/downloads/examples.jar /user/saurabh
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 hadoop fs -put /path/to/file.ext  /usr/local/hadoop/
```

Put command transfers the file from your local system to hdfs. In the line written below, the file.ext will be moved to `/usr/local/hadoop` folder and you can view it by running `hadoop fs -ls /usr/local/hadoop`

Comment: I put your comment into the answer